# Proof that if $\mathrm{tr}\,A^k=0$ for all $k=1,\ldots, n$, then $A^n = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, symmetric-polynomials, nilpotence

**Statement.**
Suppose we have a square matrix $A$ of order $n$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristics $0$ or $p>n$. There is a theorem that if $\mathrm{tr}\,A^k=0$ for all $k=1,\ldots, n$, then $A$ is nilpotent and $A^n = 0$. The problem is to prove it.

**What I did so far.**

1. Let's consider characteristic polynomial $\chi(x)$ of our matrix $A$. The Newton identities relate $\mathrm{tr}\,A^k$ to the coefficients of $\chi(x)$:
   $$
   s_k = \mathrm{tr}\,A^k
   $$
2. Since $\mathrm{tr}\,A^k=0$ for all $k=1,\ldots, n$, then $\chi(x) = x^n$ and (since we a over a field) all roots of $\chi$ are $0$. Therefor the only eigenvalue for $A$ is 0.

Now I have trouble proving first item and going from second to $A^n = 0$, How do I do those things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: Then the OP shouldn't have any difficulty going from part (2) to the end result then.

Comment: The OP has trouble getting to part 2 altogether. Read the question. (But I'll admit I read too quickly too and thought the OP knew how to get from "$\chi_A = X^n$" to "$A$ is nilpotent")

Comment: Am I OP? :) What's OP?

Comment: Original Poster. In this case, you.