# Proof for $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ that if $[A,B]=tA$ for $0\neq t\in\mathbb{F}$, then $A^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, symmetric-polynomials, nilpotence

**Statement.**
Suppose we have a square matrices $A,B$ of order $n$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristics $0$ or $p>n$. If $[A,B]=AB-BA=tA$ for some nonzero $t\in\mathbb{F}$, then $A^n=0$. The problem is to prove this statement.

**Where I've got so far.** There is an idea to take trace of both sides of equation:
$$
\mathrm{tr}\,(AB-BA)=\mathrm{tr}\,(tA)
$$
$$
\mathrm{tr}\,(AB)-\mathrm{tr}\,(BA)=t\times\mathrm{tr}\,(A)
$$
since $\mathrm{tr}\,(AB) = \mathrm{tr}\,(BA)$ (by properties of the trace) we have
$$
t\times A = \mathrm{tr}\,(A)
$$
and since $t\neq 0$, we have $\mathrm{tr}\,(A) = 0$. That's all I could get form it. What sould I do next?

Comment: Hint: [it's related to your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440738/proof-that-if-mathrmtr-ak-0-for-all-k-1-ldots-n-then-an-0).

Comment: @user1551 I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. While the question you linked certainly imply the result here (and thus one of the possible answers is "If $[A,B] = t A$ then $[A,B]$ and $A$ commute and so by this other question we're done"), there are simpler answers in this case.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I agree that it's not an exact duplicate, but several similar questions have been asked on this site. So, I picked one with the weakest condition. It's fine if the community wants to reopen this question.

Comment: @user1551 Do you know if there's another question with this condition as a hypothesis?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There is a very similar one, with $t=1$: [if $A=AB−BA$ then $A^n=0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724294/if-a-ab-ba-then-an-0), and that question has its own duplicates.

Comment: @user1551 I think closing as a duplicate of that one could be a good compromise, no?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh, actually if you let $B=t\widetilde{B}$, the two questions are the same. Maybe I should close this question using that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hints.*

1. Prove (by mathematical induction or otherwise) that $A^kB-BA^k=ktA^k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$
2. The trace of a product of matrices is invariant under cyclical permutation of the multiplicands.
3. See the question "[$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}\tr(A)=\tr(A^{2})= \ldots = \tr(A^{n})=0$ implies $A$ is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229233/declaremathoperator-trtr-tra-tra2-ldots-tran-0-implies)". Several answers to this question are applicable when the underlying field has characteristic 0 or characteristic $p>n$.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, we need to impose $t\neq0$ in order for the statement to hold. As Najib, says, this statement can be proved using the previous statement you asked about.

We have$$t\cdot\mathrm{tr}(A)=\mathrm{tr}(tA)=\mathrm{tr}(AB-BA)=0,$$which yields$$\mathrm{tr}(A)=0.$$Likewise, for any $k$, we have $tA^k=A^kB-A^{k-1}BA.$ Using an argument similar to the one above, we deduce that for any $k$, $\mathrm{tr}(A^k)=0$. Hence, $A$ is nilpotent.